# ASP NET MVC 5: RedirectToAction stops to work all of a sudden

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-routing

in my ASP.NET Project i have a form which sends data via POST to method which looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult PerformanceControl(int id, string button, ShowPerformanceControlViewModel viewModel)
{
     //some logic
     return RedirectToAction("PerformanceControl");
}
```

After the logic has run it should Redirect to the following action:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult PerformanceControl(int id)
{
     //some logic
     return View(model);
}
```

My problem is that the RedirectToAction suddenly stops working even though the redirect had worked 100 of times before. I'm using Windows Server 2012 and IIS8.
The rest of the site of the site still works its only this controller in which suddenly RedirectToAction stops working. I only get 404 for the GET request to PerformanceControl.

**Update:**

Today i found out why it doesnt work. The functions that stop working depend on an external which is hosted on the same machine. This service stops accepting requests and because there is no error handling in the controller the exception just gets fired and the RedirectToAction will never be executed. The external service logs "Connection_Dropped_List_Full DefaultAppPool" is there to flush or reset this list on IIS?

Comment: define stops working

Comment: I only get 404 for the GET request to PerformanceControl and this is all of a sudden because it work 100 times before that and not anymore, only a restart of the application brings it to life again.

Comment: @Cracksoldier For clarity those two actions are in the same controller?

Comment: Yes they are in the same controller

Comment: Could you put some code from `PerformanceControl` view?

Comment: have you changed your routing? there should be a {id} optional named sector there or else your /11 wouldn't be treated as id parameter

Comment: @D-Shih here is a pastebin with the code: https://pastebin.com/KsGrqUem  (In my defense this code is not from me, i'm just the guy who has to debug it now.) The button which ist used is on line 319.

Comment: @Steve i have not changed the routing in any way, the funny thing is it works for hours and then suddenly stops

Comment: sounds like a cache problem to me. make sure you start VS as admin and clean rebuild

Comment: Ok, i will try that and publich a clean build on my dev server.

Comment: It maybe an issue with IIS, have you looked at the log files?  The subcode for 404 could be useful to determine the cause.

Comment: I have looked into the logfiles, 'http://<mysite>/Performance/PerformanceControl/11 404 0 0 96'. The funny thing is in the log files it states that the POST command returned 404 and in the developer console of chrome it states that the GET command doesnt work

Comment: Is it possible that you are getting an exception in your code that is unhandled causing a redirect to a missing exception handler page?

Comment: I have already thought about that, is there away to configure IIS in a way that is displays me the exception? Should i add the Method to form or is it by default POST in ASP?

Comment: You should have something in your startup class like `app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");` but you should also probably wrap your logic in a try/catch block in the controller.

Comment: Today i found out that there is an httperr.log (i didnt know windows has it) my project relies on an other application and in the time where the redirection error occurs the log says this 'Connection_Dropped_List_Full DefaultAppPool'

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to the RedirectToAction needing the Id passed. Try this:

```
return RedirectToAction("PerformanceControl", new { Id = id });
```

Comment: I get the message in the browser 404: https://<my-site>/Performance/PerformanceControl/11 could not be found. It looks like that he gets the id.

Comment: I'm fairly new to ASP.NET i start at '/Performance/PerformanceControl/11' and send my post how does the framework keep the id at the end. In ASP.NET i have not really a clue, should I add the new{ Id = id} to make sure its there, or does this make no difference in ASP?

Comment: Anytime you do a RedirectToAction, any parameters you're expecting from your [Get] method should be included in method call like demonstrated to prevent some odd bugs. ASP.NET will handle mapping into the default binding/query string of the redirect, and then handle mapping to the method parameters from your action.

Comment: .NET is keeping the values of your Id because you have it in the URL path already. I would still not assume and explicitly pass your id route values. The source code then attempts to merge route values, which is keeping the Id in the URL: https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/Controller.cs#L502